# Manipulate package weight before shipping rates calculation

Tags: shipping, magento2.2.2

I need to add some logic to weight package calculation before shipping rates are calculated. So I created a custom module with an observer on `sales_quote_address_collect_totals_after` event.

The observer looks like this

```
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class AfterCollectTotals implements ObserverInterface{

   public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer){


    foreach ($items as $item) {

         // My custom logic here to get the correct weight in $weight

    }
        $observer->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->setWeight($weight);
    }
}
```

Weight appears to be set correctly, but when the Shipping Rates are calculated this value is ignored. 
In the carrier model, `$request->getPackageWeight()` returns the package weight before my manipulation.

Where am I wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried `sales_quote_address_collect_totals_before` instead `..._after`?

Comment: Yes, but this event is dispatched too late as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've find the solution.

I didn't have to use the observer but the right way is to override

> class Shipping in Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total

I added my custom logic to `public function collect` and my custom weight is used to calculate the shipping rates

Comment: The reason is that the event sales_quote_address_collect_totals_after is dispatched after that the shipping methods collect quote totals to calculate rates

Answer (score 0):

Same problem.
Im setting new weight on checkout_cart_product_add_after Event.
Weight is set, but the shipping costs are wrong.
How to recalculate the shipping costs?
Has anyone some code snippes please?